# Using a list inside NDSolve

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics

I have a coupled differential eqations:

```
eq1[z_] := y1'[z] == c1 y1[z] + c2 y2[z];
eq2[z_] := y2'[z] == c1 y1[z] - c2 y2[z];
boundary = {y1[0] == 1, y2[0] == 0};
var = {y1, y2};
```

where `c1` and `c2` are constants.

To solve this I generally use the following codes:

```
eq[x1_, x2_, z_] := Flatten[{eq1[x1, x2, z], eq2[x1, x2, z], boundry}];
Sol[x1_, x2_] := NDSolve[eq[x1, x2, z], var, {z, 0, 5}];
```

Now if there is a table of `c1` and `c2` values. Lets say: `v={{2.65691, 2.26358}, {3.84167, 2.44838}, {3.08054,2.81354}, {3.15585,4.45893}, {1.13949, 3.25856}}`. I want to solve these above set of equations using these `c1` and `c2` values. My query is how can I include these `c1,c2` values in `NDSolve` to get the solutions for each set of `{c1,c2}`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ParametricNDSolveValue` or `ParametricNDSolve`

```
sols = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y1'[z] == c1*y1[z] + c2*y2[z], 
    y2'[z] == c1*y1[z] - c2*y2[z], y1[0] == 1, y2[0] == 0}, {y1, 
    y2}, {z, 0, 5}, {c1, c2}];
v = {{2.65691, 2.26358}, {3.84167, 2.44838}, {3.08054, 
    2.81354}, {3.15585, 4.45893}, {10.13949, 30.25856}};
Table[Through@sols[Sequence @@ index][z], {index, v}]
Table[ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[Through@sols[Sequence @@ index][z]], {z, 0, 5}], {index, 
  v}]
```

**OP**

Your approach is also work.

```
eq1[c1_, c2_, z_] := y1'[z] == c1 y1[z] + c2 y2[z];
eq2[c1_, c2_, z_] := y2'[z] == c1 y1[z] - c2 y2[z];
boundary = {y1[0] == 1, y2[0] == 0};
var = {y1, y2};
eq[c1_, c2_, z_] := 
  Flatten[{eq1[c1, c2, z], eq2[c1, c2, z], boundary}];
Sol[c1_, c2_] := NDSolve[eq[c1, c2, z], var, {z, 0, 5}];
v = {{2.65691, 2.26358}, {3.84167, 2.44838}, {3.08054, 
    2.81354}, {3.15585, 4.45893}, {1.13949, 3.25856}};
Table[Sol[Sequence @@ index], {index, v}]
(* Sol[Sequence @@ #] & /@ v *)
```

Answer (score 2):

More an extended comment on the answer (+1) by cvgmt than a distinct answer.  Instead of `Table[Through@sols[Sequence @@ ...` use

```
s = sols @@@ v;
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Map[#[z] &, s, {2}], {z, 0, 5}]
```

to obtain much more compact code.  Replacing `{y1, y2}` by `{y1[z], y2[z]}` in `ParametricNDSolveValue` further reduces the code to

```
s = sols @@@ v;
ParametricPlot[s, {z, 0, 5}]
```

Formatting the plot,

```
vs = ToString /@ v;
ParametricPlot[s, {z, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[vs, LabelStyle -> {Bold, 12}], {.2, .7}]]
```

yields

[image]

The first curve ends at about `{5 10^6, 2 10^6]` and so cannot be seen on this plot.

Comment: Thanks your code !

Comment: Thank you, @bbgodfrey. This code is very compact.